# onStyleRow event does not retain on doing sorting, filtering or pagination

Tags: javascript, dojo, dojox.grid.datagrid

I have using dojo 1.10 enhanced grid. Here, I am using **onStyleRow** event where I will style the row. It works perfect on the first load but when I tried to do **paging, sorting and filtering**, it does not know the remember the rows and apply new style on the old row index. Such as if I highlighted **2** and **4** row while on load. Now when I do the sorting the rows data will change but here it applies new style to 2 and 4 row again irrespective of the rows changed. Is this a bug in the existing code?

I am doing like this -

```
 dojo.connect(mygrid, 'onStyleRow', this, function(row) {
  if (fixedDataItems[row.index] == '1' && hideFixesVisibility == 'Editable')  //some condition
      row.customStyles += 'background-color: blue !important;';
  else
      row.customStyles += 'color: black !important;';
  });
```

I have not found anything related to it in document. Does anyone has knowledge of this?

Comment: here you are doing it on row.index hence when you sort, style is applied to the index. You have to apply the style to the row item object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

http://jsfiddle.net/bnqkodup/374/

**HTML**

```
<div id="container" class="claro">
    <div id="gridDiv"></div>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
dojo.require("dojox.grid.EnhancedGrid");
dojo.require("dojo.data.ItemFileWriteStore");
dojo.require("dojo.on");

dojo.ready(function (on) {
    /*set up data store*/
    var data = {
        identifier: 'id',
        items: []
    };
    var data_list = [{
        col1: "normal",
        col2: false,
        col3: 'But are not followed by two hexadecimal',
        col4: 29.91
    }, {
        col1: "important",
        col2: false,
        col3: 'Because a % sign always indicates',
        col4: 9.33
    }, {
        col1: "important",
        col2: false,
        col3: 'Signs can be selectively',
        col4: 19.34
    }];
    var rows = 60;
    for (var i = 0, l = data_list.length; i < rows; i++) {
        data.items.push(dojo.mixin({
            id: i + 1
        }, data_list[i % l]));
    }
    var store = new dojo.data.ItemFileWriteStore({
        data: data
    });
function formatLink(value){
        return '<a href="#">'+value+'</a>';
    }
    /*set up layout*/
    var layout = [
        [{
            'name': 'Column 1',
            'field': 'id',
            formatter: formatLink

        }, {
            'name': 'Column 2',
            'field': 'col2'
        }, {
            'name': 'Column 3',
            'field': 'col3',
            'width': '230px'
        }, {
            'name': 'Column 4',
            'field': 'col4',
            'width': '230px'
        }]
    ];

    /*create a new grid:*/
    var grid = new dojox.grid.EnhancedGrid({
        id: 'grid',
        store: store,
        structure: layout,
        rowSelector: '20px'
    },
    document.createElement('div'));

    /*append the new grid to the div*/
    dojo.byId("gridDiv").appendChild(grid.domNode);

    /*Call startup() to render the grid*/
    grid.startup();

    //dojo.on(grid,"CellClick",function(evt){

    /* <=search for the column here */
   //var idx = evt.cellIndex;
   //var cellNode = evt.cellNode;
   //if(cellNode){
      //cellNode.style.backgroundColor = "green";
   // }
    //if(evt.cellIndex==1){
    //this.set('style','background-color:red;');
   // }
   // });
     dojo.connect(grid, 'onStyleRow', this, function(row) {
  var item = grid.getItem(row.index);
        if(item){
        //console.log(store);
            var type = store.getValue(item,'col1',null);

            if(type == "normal"){
                row.customStyles += "color:red;";
                //row.customClasses += " dismissed";
            }
        }
  });
});
```

**CSS**

```
@import"../lib/dojo/resources/dojo.css";
 @import"../lib/dijit/themes/claro/claro.css";
 @import"../lib/dojox/grid/enhanced/resources/claro/EnhancedGrid.css";
 @import"../lib/dojox/grid/enhanced/resources/EnhancedGrid_rtl.css";

/*Grid need a explicit width/height by default*/
 #grid {
    width: 1110px;
    height: 494px;
    color: #000000;
}
```

Comment: Could you please explain me what this line does    var type = store.getValue(item,'col1',null);  Why we have col1 there?

Comment: It reads the value of column 1 from the store. Look into your data_list, col1 values are 'normal', 'important' and 'important'. Once the value is equal to 'normal', that row is highlighted.

Comment: So here it will always check the value of the first column and based on that it will apply a style. So can I pass variable for each column in my grid say 1 and 2 where 1 will do a change and 2 will make it remain as it is.

Comment: color only shows when we mouse hover over grid...but we cant have startup after the applying color as we are having showing grid then on clicking button we apply color...so is there any way to refresh the enhanced grid. We have tried dijit.byId('grid').resize() but it didnt work. Any other method?

Comment: If you want to color the columns during load you need to use formatter function. Another way is to try and use onShow event and see if you can colour the grid. But I would be going for formatter first